# Comprehensive list of D&D products

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, collector-value

I’m not sure I can ask this here, but lately I have been expanding my personal collection of Dungeons and Dragons products. Does anyone know if there is somewhere (official or unofficial) a complete dungeons and dragons products list? Where I could check or uncheck as I get them?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a shopping question. The only issue that might arise would be that the list is out of scope - speak more than 30k characters long. So in that regard, you might want to focus on a particular line of products that suits this stack - for instance, what are all of the roleplaying books, what is an exhaustive list of all dragon magazines etc.

Comment: This question has been flagged as off-topic.  It includes the tag "collector-value", which seems to be a supported tag (four other questions tagged this, with one closed for being not focused, but not off-topic).  I would appreciate if those who vote to close either comment on why this is off-topic or link to the appropriate meta.

Comment: You could cross-link each question to the other questions, for example, ask one question about all the die, one about all the magazines, etc.

Comment: The problem I see with the question is that it *is* asking us to list a bunch of resources and each answer could be equally valid. There could be a dozen (especially unofficial) websites out there that contain D&D product lists and there's not way for us to determine which ones are any better or worse than any others or answer the question any better or worse than another answer. The [collector-value] tag is a supported tag on this Stack, though I'm not sure it and [product ident] are relevant for this question, but the other 4 questions using the tag aren't asking for a list of resources.

Comment: @Akixkisu If this question is asking us for recommendations for an *external* resource that lists all D&D products, then it's a shopping question. If it's asking us to build & curate a list in an answer here on the site, then it's **way** too broad.

Comment: @ObliviousSage yes, therefore the suggestion to compartmentalise it into questions suited to the stack, see comments above. As I stated - the question as asked currently is out of scope (an answer would take more than 30k characters). I don't think we are in disagreement here, except on how we read it (shopping vs out of scope).